# Interpreting conditional expectation of brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm trying to gain an intuitive understanding of conditional expectation of a function of brownian motion.
Let $B_t$ be a brownian motion starting at $x$, and $f$ a bounded function. Is it right to state
$$
E[f(B_t) \mid B_0 = x] = E[f(B_t - x) \mid B_0 = 0] = E[f(B_t - x)]
$$
? Since you shift the brownian motion path down $x$ unit, you have a new brownian motion starting at $0$. But since the path stays the same, so the conditional expectation of $f(B_t)$ stay the same?

Comment: Can't be right. If $B_0=0$ we don't have to condition on this. If you take a very small $t$ and a function $f$ that is non zero only in a small neighbourhood of $x$ and $x\not=0$ it is pretty obvious that $0\not=f(x)\approx E[f(B_t)]\not=E[f(B_t-x)]\approx f(0)\approx 0$ since $B_t-x$ is concentrated around zero (make $x$ very large).